# Passing PHP Next Page Variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to pass the php variable to the next page.

I tried many things, but I did not succeed.
Here is the attached case I tried.

**index code**

```
<script>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_passwd,$db_name);

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from StoreTable");

$n = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $name = $row['name'];
  ?>
  positions_1.push({ content:
    '<div class="wrap">' +
    ' <div><a href="next.php?name=<?= $name; ?>" target="_blank" class="link">next page</a></div>' +
    '</div>'
  });
  <?
$n++;
}
?>
</script>
```

**next code**

```
<?php 
    echo $name;
?>
```

url has been changed to a variable, but a blank screen is displayed. (Variables were not passed to the next page.)

Comment: `echo $_GET['name'];`

Comment: does the code look correct when you view the source? What do you do with the javascript `positions_1` array?

Comment: To expand on @Qirel's comment -- `$name` doesn't get set unless you have `register_globals` defined, which is a really bad idea and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
<script>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_passwd,$db_name);

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from StoreTable");

$n = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $name = $row['name'];
  ?>
  positions_1.push({ content:
    '<div class="wrap">' +
    ' <div><a href="next.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>" target="_blank" class="link">next page</a></div>' +
    '</div>'
  });
  <?
$n++;
}
?>
</script>
```